Why only one database for django apps in the tutorial?
I'm in need for another application in my django website but fail to understand how to extend my knowledge from the tutorial.
Following the tutorial, my project structure looks like this:
- mydjango/
  - db.sqlite
  - firstapp/
  - mysite/

The tutorial states

… An app can be in multiple projects. …

My understanding of that quote and django, is, that concerns are separated.
However the database handling in the tutorial contradicts that concept.

How can an app be in another project? The project's database sits not even in the parent project's directory. Everything is just mixed up in one database.
Why does each app not have it's own database?


You appear to be confusing apps, projects and databases. An app doesn't have any database per se. It just defines models and views (and perhaps other things). A project combines several apps into one working "thing". And databases are configured at the project level. And one project typically has one database, but you can configure multiple databases per project and even set it up so each app in your project uses a different database.

What is mysite/? A subproject? Another app?

@16171413 A project

So mydjango/ is the parent directory containing the project, db and apps. Not related to your question but IMO creating a project with django-admin startproject mysite . gives a better structure to your project.


How can an app be in another project? The project's database sits not even in the parent project's directory. Everything is just mixed up in one database.

Not all apps sit in a project directory. In fact probably most of your apps don't. django.contrib.auth for example, is an app offered by Django, that sits in the Django repository itself.
A lot of Django packages export a django app. You can install that, for example through pip, and as long as it is in the scope of Python interpreter, you can import it.

Why does each app not have it's own database?

That would probably be a (very) bad idea: each app can work with zero, one, or more databases, and the routing can be done through a database router, or by using .using(…) [Django-doc]. A lot of models defined in the apps link to each other. For example a lot of models have a foreign key to auth.User (the User model defined in the django.contrib.auth app). If these would have been defined in a separate database, then you can not enforce FOREIGN KEY constraints, don't make JOINs efficiently, etc. so it would severely limit what you can do with a model.
I think that while it is true that "a project can have multiple apps", at that moment in the tutorial, it is not very relevant. Only after a certain amount of time splitting the project into reusable components is useful. So if you follow the tutorial, I would at the moment view this more as a detail that will eventually indeed become quite important.
Django essentially aims to separate the application logic from the database(s). In the DATABASES setting [Django-doc], you can define multiple databases, and these can be different sorts of databases (PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, SQLite, MongoDB, etc.). Then by using a database router [Django-doc] or by specifying the database explicitly in a query, you can pick the database you want to use, and thus even dynamically switch for example. Django aims to be dialect-invariant, although this has some limitations, it thus means that if you don't use advanced database functionalities, you can trade one type of database for another without changing your code. Applications are orthogonal to the database: they don't per se have much to do with the database picked.

It would  be useful if you also highlight that the databases can be configured in the settings and DBs other than SQLite can be used and even the default SQLite can be configured to be in an entirely separate directory.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, I've added an extra section.
